# up-to-date commit message template after pre-commit hook

Tags: git, githooks

I want to set up my git hooks so that when I commit something, an artifact is automatically produced if not up-to-date with the codebase, then staged and committed together with the rest of the manually staged files.

I know it's not necessarily a best practice, but I'm still experimenting at this point and I would like to have this option; another option would be to make the `pre-commit` hook fail if the artifact is outdated and then manually stage it, but since the artifact is only needed by the CI pipeline this would be a probably useless additional step.

I'm currently producing the artifact and staging it (by `git add artifact`) in the `pre-commit` hook. It's working.

The issue is that the commit message template (the one that pops out when I edit a new commit message in my editor) does not reflect the updated index (after the `pre-commit` hook modified it by staging the new artifact).

Any idea on how to keep that message up-to-date?

I was looking into `prepare-commit-msg`: I can manipulate the outdated message there. Is there a command that output the whole content of the file `COMMIT_EDITMSG`? Maybe I could rerun it somehow and replace the file content...

**EDIT:** I'm looking at the source code. It seems that the message is composed in the code, not by a command (inside the [prepare_to_commit](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e5a14ddd2d93da4d951fd63d4f78fe2410debe68/builtin/commit.c#L713) function, half hard-coded half output of `status_printf` and `status_printf_ln`). [The pre-commit is called](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e5a14ddd2d93da4d951fd63d4f78fe2410debe68/builtin/commit.c#L731) before [the message is composed](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e5a14ddd2d93da4d951fd63d4f78fe2410debe68/builtin/commit.c#L888), but from the same function, which could explain why the message is outdated (my `git add` command does not modify that function state). This does not bode well.

Comment: The prepare-commit-msg hook is run with at least one parameter, which is the name of the file containing the existing, so-far, prepared message. The job of this hook is to edit that file. You can write this hook in any language you like as long as the result is something Git can run through your OS's `exec` system call. This program can do anything you can do in any program you write. You will have to write the program, though. See also [the githooks documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

Comment: @torek I'm aware! The file that `prepare-commit-msg` takes as first argument is `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`, that's why I asked how it's composed in the first place: I'm guessing there's a command that outputs that content, maybe using a default template. But either that command is run before my `pre-commit` hook (so I would need to run it again after `git add`) or the index is not fully updated by that `git add`.
I know I could simply rewrite the message in the `prepare-commit-msg` hook by I'd rather not reinvent the wheel...

Comment: You'll kind of have to, since (as you discovered) the `git commit` code is where the initial message is made and it's not very flexible here. Be aware that if you try to modify the index / staging-area in the pre-commit hook, this works fine with *some* `git commit` operations, and not with others (e.g., `git commit --only file.ext`).

Comment: That, I did not know. This is bad, using `--only` leaves the index in a confusing state (the file staged in the `pre-commit` is both staged and unstaged). This is the nail in the coffin, I guess: thank you! I'll reply to the question to summarize.

Comment: If it is only needed by the CI pipeline, why don't you have the CI pipeline build it as part of the pipeline? Do you really need to commit it?

Comment: This whole affair is a bit of a kludge, but yes, it needs to be committed: the artifact I'm talking about is itself a ci job configuration file. It needs to be committed and up-to-date with the rest of the codebase or the ci process will run incorrectly. What I would need to do is, as the first ci job, check if the artifact is up-to-date, if not: cancel all remaining job, update the artifact, commit the update and push it, which would trigger another ci run. I guess it would work but it would also clutter the ci process and the git history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way the initial commit message is produced, it seems there's no easy way to leverage directly that code (see my edit).

A manual rewrite is needed, but as it turned out, it's not that difficult to achieve. This is a `prepare-commit-msg` hook that does what I wanted:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# The file containing the default commit message
COMMIT_MSG_FILE=$1

# Clear the old git status from the default message: since it's 
# the last default fragment we can clear till the end of the file
sed -i '/# On branch/,$d' $COMMIT_MSG_FILE

# Recompute the git status, without newcomers hints and comment it out
status=$(git -c "advice.statusHints=false" status | awk '{print "# " $0}')

# Write the new status to the commit message
cat << EOF >> $COMMIT_MSG_FILE
$status
EOF
```

### BUT! DO NOT DO THIS!

As in, don't stage files from the `pre-commit` hook (the message rewrite itself should be fine). As [@torek pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68877105/up-to-date-commit-message-template-after-pre-commit-hook/68879891#comment121730246_68877105), some commit commands (like `git commit --only`) may result in a confusing state.